# phpmyadmin mySQL Query for joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table A -

```
SNo     ID     Place
1      1000    Null
2      Null    Null
3      1020    CityX
```

And another table B -

```
 ID     Place
1000    CityY
2000    CityZ
4040    CityAA
```

Now, I need to join table A and B such that I can get the values of Place in table A from table B. So my final table should look like this -

```
SNo     ID     Place
1      1000    CityY
2      1020    CityX
```

I'm trying to create an SQL query with joins, but that is only giving me empty rows. I did -

```
Select * from A
left outer join B
on A.ID = B.ID
where A.ID IS NOT NULL
```

Where is my query breaking? How do I get the expected result?

Comment: I removed the irrelevant tags; this question doesn't actually have anything to do with PHP or PHPMyAdmin. Note that PHPMyAdmin is *not* the database; it's just a user interface for MySQL.

Comment: Is there such a case that there is an `ID` in table `B` that isn't in the table `A`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need inner join

```
Select A.ID,  ifnull(A.Place, B.Place) from A
Inner join B
on A.ID = B.ID
where A.ID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: When Place is present in A, I want to take it from A, and if it's not present in A and is available in B, I want to take it from B.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.Sno, A.ID, IF(A.Place is null, B.Place, A.place) as Place from A
left join B
on A.ID = B.ID
where A.ID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is nothing wrong with your query, here is a working sqlfiddle of your question

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29a002/1/0

Since you didn't post your actual schema or screenshot of it, I am going to suspect incompatible column definitions or invalid data

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it like this Select the Place field of table B instead.

```
select SNo, B.ID, B.Place 
from A
left outer join B
on A.ID = B.ID
```